Spring Conext is initializing my ApplicationProperties Bean twice in my Integration Tests
I am trying to create a Junit extension to create a S3 Mock server before all tests and shut it down after all Tests. The S3 Mock server is supposed to use values from my ApplicationProperties class, which in term is a @ConfigurationProperties class.
Now I am using this simple test:
@ExtendWith({S3Extension.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest()
class S3OtherServiceItTest {
  @Autowired private S3Service s3Service;
  @MockBean SetupSchedulerJobs setupSchedulerJobs;
  @MockBean DbStatus dbStatus;

  @Test
  public void test(AmazonS3Client client) throws IOException, FileException {
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    Files.write(file.toPath(), "contents".getBytes());

    s3Service.uploadLocalFile(file.getPath(), "another/file/name");

    client.listObjects("tkgpdf-bucket").getObjectSummaries().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}


And as of now this is my Junit Extension:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class S3Extension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, ParameterResolver {
  private S3Mock s3Mock;
  private AmazonS3Client s3Client;
  private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

  @Override
  public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context)  {
    applicationProperties = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context).getBean(ApplicationProperties.class);

    s3Mock = new S3Mock.Builder().withPort(9000).withFileBackend("build/s3").build();
    s3Mock.start();

    s3Client = getClient();
    s3Client.createBucket(applicationProperties.getS3().getBucket());
  }

  @Override
  public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) {
    if (s3Mock != null) {
      s3Mock.shutdown();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supportsParameter(
          ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext)
          throws ParameterResolutionException {
    return parameterContext.getParameter().getType() == AmazonS3Client.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Object resolveParameter(
          ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext)
          throws ParameterResolutionException {
    return s3Client;
  }

  public AmazonS3Client getClient() {
    AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpoint =
            new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(applicationProperties.getS3().getEndpoint(), "us-west-2");
    return (AmazonS3Client)
            AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint)
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new AnonymousAWSCredentials()))
                    .build();
  }
}

With this configuration the Test will fail with an Error something like:
Failed to resolve bean as there is 2 Beans of the Type ApplicationProperties
So, why are two ApplicationProperties Beans being instanciated and how do I avoid this? My suspicion is that the @SpringBootTest annotation and the SpringExtension are both trying to create the context resulting in this error?

Your suspicion is wrong. What does your ApplicationProperties look like, what does your configuration look like? Please add those things to the question.

ALso why is this an extension, why aren't you doing all of this just in an @TestConfiguration so you can just inject it as a regular bean (or let Spring inject it into your test method).
